# How to create python program, multiple of 3 with while loops

Tags: python

ok first sorry if my english is bad

i want to ask how to create python programs multiple of 3 with while loop, like this:

```
i=0
while i < 10:
   i += 1
   if i == 3:
     continue
   print(i)

output:
1
2
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

so i want to eliminate the number 3 6 9, can anyone help me ? i newbie :'v thanks.

Comment: `if i%3 == 0: continue`

Comment: how to print the numbers upside down?
example

1 number 10
2 number 9
3 number 8

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
i=0
while i < 10:
   i += 1
   if i % 3 == 0:
     continue
   print(i)
```

Comment: how to print the numbers upside down? 
example 
1 number 10 
2 number 9 
3 number 8

Answer (score 1):

It seems as if you want to print the numbers in reverse order (backwards/upside-down), so here is the snippet of code to achieve that task:

```
i=10
while i > 0:
   if i%3 != 0:
     print(i)
   i-=1
```

The value of 'i' is the number which it will start counting down from.

Comment: so, i mean including 2 numbers in one programs. like 1 Bina Darma University 10, 2 Bina Darma University 9

Comment: Sorry Kanichi I don't really know what you mean

Comment: And when did Bina Darma University get included in all of this?

Comment: Ok great, so could you put my answer as correct then?